# Nested view in stateProvider AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have worked on `$routeProvider` for quiet sometime and now I think I might have one requirement where it would be better if I implement `$stateProvider` as it has upper hand over `$routeProvider`.

I am trying to implement nested view in  [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FTXfGRbRMywoiuFaJbXq?p=preview) but I think I have misunderstood something and so my `hqChild@about1` is not working. Its implemented under html

> About --> Contact Us --> HeadQuater address --> Mobile Number: (BLANK)

```
.state('about1',{
  url: '/about',
  views:{
    '': {templateUrl: 'partial-about.html'},
    'ofc@about1' : { template: 'Office Address here' },
    'hq@about1' : {
      templateUrl: 'hq-adr.html',
      controller: function($scope){
        $scope.msg= "HeadQuater Address here"
      },
      view:{
        'hqChild@about1': {template: '+91-99999 99999'}
      }

    }
  }
})
```

From what I understood from internet, `viewname@statename` is the syntax.

Comment: what is not working in your code?

Comment: You meant to say `hqChild` isn't showing phonenumber?

Comment: @PankajParkar: Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your plunker a bit, I assume what you wanted to achieve is insert the hqchild template to the `<div ui-view="hqChild"></div>` in `hq-adr.html`. here is the edited [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5JhdMjQlnpl7xRzY5Ha6?p=preview).

I don't think nest `veiw:` under a named views is valid in ui-router. The change I did is the following

```
.state('about1',{
  url: '/about',
  views:{
    '': {templateUrl: 'partial-about.html'},
    'ofc@about1' : { template: 'Office Address here' },
    'hq@about1' : {
      templateUrl: 'hq-adr.html',
      controller: function($scope){
        $scope.msg= "HeadQuater Address here"
      }
    },
    'hqChild@about1': {template: '+91-99999 99999'}
  }
})
```